# Avg price for other sales orders that happen in the same interval per a client- BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am stuck and I cannot even figure out potential directions. I have the following sales data in BigQuery that shows a sales order per a client done on a certain day:
[image]

```
    SELECT ARRAY[
        '1', '2', '1', '4', '5'
    ] AS client_id,
    ARRAY[
      '2023-01-01', '2022-10-12', '2023-04-04', '2023-02-01', '2022-04-01'
    ] AS sale_date,
    ARRAY[
      'A', 'B', 'A', 'D', 'A'
    ] AS package,
      ARRAY[
      1, 3, 4, 5, 6
    ] AS price
```

I need to determine whether a sale was an upsale (sales order price > avg price of sales orders for other packages that were created for other clients before) or downsale (sales order price < avg price of sales orders for other packages that were created for other clients before) per a client.

Here is the desired output:

[image]

And here is the step-by-step calculation:

[image]

The logic I am considering: get the previous sale_date per client X package; calculate avg of price for other accounts with sale_date between sale_date and previous sales_date.

I am a bit stuck with the practical implementation and will be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See example and comments

```
with cte1 as(
select t1.sale_id,t1.client_id,t1.sale_date,t1.package,t1.price,t1.apu 
    -- max date before for t2.client_id=t1.client_id or t2.package=t1.package
  ,max(t2.sale_date) as prev_sale_date
from sales t1
left join sales t2 on  t2.sale_date<t1.sale_date
   and (t2.client_id=t1.client_id or t2.package=t1.package)
group by t1.sale_id,t1.client_id,t1.sale_date,t1.package,t1.price,t1.apu 
)
select t1.sale_id,t1.client_id,t1.package,t1.sale_date,t1.price,t1.apu
  -- avg for (t2.sale_date>t1.prev_sale_date or t1.prev_sale_date is null)
    -- t1.prev_sale_date is null - thats all previous rows
  ,avg(t2.price) avg_price 
  ,case when t1.price>avg(t2.price) then 'upsale'
        when t1.price<avg(t2.price) then 'downsale'
        when t1.price=avg(t2.price) then 'eq_sale'
   else 'undef'
  end up_down
from cte1 t1
left join cte1 t2 on t2.sale_date<t1.sale_date 
  and (t2.sale_date>t1.prev_sale_date or t1.prev_sale_date is null)
group by t1.sale_id,t1.client_id,t1.package,t1.sale_date,t1.price,t1.apu
order by t1.sale_id
```

I'll add columns sale_id - for clearly row identification in example, and `apu` - your avg_previous_unlock - to compare request result and desirable data. You can remove this columns. They do not affect the result.

However, it is highly desirable to have a row identifier.

cte1 result is

| sale_id | client_id | sale_date | package | price | apu | prev_sale_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5 | 2022-04-01 | A | 6 | 3 | null |
| 1002 | 2 | 2022-10-12 | B | 3 | 6 | null |
| 1003 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | A | 1 | 3 | 2022-04-01 |
| 1004 | 4 | 2023-02-01 | D | 5 | 3.3 | null |
| 1005 | 1 | 2023-04-04 | A | 4 | 5 | 2023-01-01 |

query result

| sale_id | client_id | package | sale_date | price | apu | avg_price | up_down |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 5 | A | 2022-04-01 | 6 | 3 | null | undef |
| 1002 | 2 | B | 2022-10-12 | 3 | 6 | 6 | downsale |
| 1003 | 1 | A | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 3 | 3 | downsale |
| 1004 | 4 | D | 2023-02-01 | 5 | 3.3 | 3.33333333333333 | upsale |
| 1005 | 1 | A | 2023-04-04 | 4 | 5 | 5 | downsale |

Probably, query can be written easier if you use window functions.

cte1 another variant

```
select t1.*
  ,(select max(sale_date) from sales t2 where t2.sale_date<t1.sale_date
   and (t2.client_id=t1.client_id or t2.package=t1.package) 
   ) as prev_sale_date
from sales t1
```

Comment: it worked like a charm! Thank you for helping with this problem!